# display soy variable value like alert in javascript

Tags: google-closure-templates, soy-templates

Do we have anything equivalent to javascript alert() in soy file to display variable values?

I tried using javascript also in soy like below but didnt help (extendedFieldView is a List):

```
<#assign extendedField = extendedFieldView.ExtendedField>
<script type="text/javascript">   
alert("${extendedField}")
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to debug, or do you actually need alert? Can you just print out values?